# In my 2d game I want the character to rotate but not the camera

Tags: game-engine

The camera is being parented by the character's armature. Its a 2d side stroller game and i want the camera to follow the character but i want the character to rotate without the camera following and rotating behind the background. The link to my game is http://www.mediafire.com/file/97i8ndd1jd99yf8/BlackHole_Game.blend

Comment: Use a Vertex Parent. And use [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to unload your blend file in the future.

Comment: so if i understand it correctly, you only want the camera to move in 1D direction (left right) even if the character rotates? In that case, you could remove the parent, but use 'copy location' instead as constraint for the camera, where target is the armature and check the axis you want the camera to follow the armature